# Operadores de comparación uso de (!) en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Me han dado el siguiente código para entenderlo, y hay cosas que no acabo de entender o yo las haría de otra manera y no veo la ventaja de la manera como está hecho, aunque seguramente se deba a que no las entiendo del todo.

```js
class Contact {
  // TODO : When the program works, delete email parameter
  constructor(name = "", surname = "", email = "unknown@unknown.fr") {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.email = email;

    if (!this.checkNameIsOk()) {
      console.log("Valor retornado de checkNameIsOk: " + this.checkNameIsOk());
      this.setName();
    }
    if (!this.validateEmail(this.email)) {
      this.setEmail();
    }
  }

  // Por qué hacer la evaluación en dos pasos y no directamente en el if
  checkNameIsOk() {
    console.log("estamos dentro del metodo CheckName");
    let CheckName = this.name.length;
    console.log("este es checkname valor retornado: " + CheckName);
    return CheckName >= 2;
  }
```

La parte que no acabo de entender es `if (!this.checkNameIsOk())` sé que lo que haces es llamar al método

```js
 checkNameIsOk(){
  return this.name.length >= 2;
 }
```

pero lo que no acabo de entender, es la lógica de `if(!this.checkNameIsOk())`

Lo que me confunde es el signo ! porque hasta donde he podido ver, el valor que retorna el método es 0 que sería false (tengo un console.log dentro del método para ver el valor y otro console.log dentro del if para ver qué es lo que recibe).

Resumiendo, no entiendo por que poner como retorno `return this.name.length >= 2;` cuando podría ser un 0 sin más. Aunque en este punto, prefiero preguntar a estarme equivocando y quedarme con la duda.

Gracias.

Comment: He puesto el signo ! entre paréntesis porque por alguna razón en el título se cambiaba a ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El signo `!` sirve para negar tu condicon, por ejemplo si el metodo `this.checkNameIsOk()` retorna `true` lo convierte a `false` y viceversa.

Puede intentar en la consola de tu navegador ejecutando: `console.log(!true);` o `console.log(!false)`

Solo valores 'verdaderos pueden "entrar" al `if`. Lo que quieren es hacer algo cuando `this.checkNameIsOk()` retorne `false`.

En cuanto a `return this.name.length >= 2;` es evaluar si la longitud de `this.name` es mayor o igual a 2, si esto pasa entonces retornaria `true` de lo contrario `false`. 
Es algo similar a:

```
if (this.name.length >= 2) {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

Si miras son mas lineas de codigo. Recuerda que los operadores relacionales en JS siempre regresan un valor booleano, entonces lo puedes aprovechar de esa manera : `this.name.length >= 2; // false or true`

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta. Me ha sido de gran ayuda. Si estuvieras cerca te invito una birra seguro seguro.